# How to correctly define this Observation Space for the custom Gym environment I am creating using Gym.Scpaces.Box?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, ddpg

I am trying to implement DDPG algorithm of the [Paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9627230).

Here in the image below, gk[n] and rk[n] are KxM matrices of real values.
Theta[n] and v[n] are arrays of size M.

I want to write correct code to **specify state/observation space in my custom environment**.

*Since the data
type input to the neural network needs to be unified, the state
array can be expressed as*

[image: The state Space definition as mentioned in the Paper]

`observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(K, M), dtype=np.float16......)`

I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use stable-baselines3, you may use a `Dict` observation space filled with `Box`es with meaningful limits for all your vectors and matrices (if limits are unknown, you may always use `+inf/-inf`). The code could be something like:

```
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Box, Dict

class MySuperGymEnv(Env):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    spaces = {
       'theta': Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(99,), dtype=np.float32),
       'g': Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(100,200), dtype=np.float32),
       ...
    }
    self.observation_space = Dict(spaces)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to ask how should I proceed with specifying limits on g , v, r as they have complex values.
Also, as shown in the screenshot, state space looks something like = 
{real(theta, g, v, r), imag(theta, g, v, r)}. Should I then create a Dict(dict of arrays)?

Comment: you can use your distinction between real and imaginary parts as a 2nd dimension for vectors and as a 3rd dimension for matrices in your `shape` parameter; `low` and `high` can be also vectors, therefore specifying limits for every element